# I want to change the position of gridView from default bottom to top in right side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" PagerStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" but its not working

this is the gridview code

Comment: those properties adjust the position of the pager control within the gridview. Is that what you want, or is the position of the whole gridview within the overall page? It's not clear.

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? It improved the post.

Comment: [code block usage guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

in Theme.css

```
.GridPosition
    {
        position:fixed;
        right:50px;
        top:50px;   
    }
```

in default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Theme.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewTrain" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" onrowdeleting="GridView_Train_RowDeleting" onselectedindexchanging="GridView_SelectedIndexChanging"class="GridPosition">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Edit" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```